# Accessing wordpress database in Flutter mobile app

Tags: android, database, wordpress, flutter

How can i get the user information on my mobile app, which was added from my website using flutter? I am able to get posts and comments using REST API, but for the users i am getting:

> code  "rest_user_cannot_view"
>   message "Sorry, you are not allowed to list users."
>   data
>   status  401

Comment: What wast the URL you used?

Comment: https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users

Comment: When i disable the plugin Wordfence security, i am only able to see the admin user and not all the subscribed users.

Comment: I found the solution!